# Getting a number divisible by five with Math.Round

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

I have a number variable that is between 0 and 100. It ccould be something like 83.333334.

I want to use `Math.Round` to round the number (e.g. `Math.round(83.333334);`). How can I do this so that the result is always divisible by five (i.e. in the set [0, 5, 10, 15... 85, 90, 95, 100])?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Divide by 5, round it, multiply by 5.

```
alert(Math.round(83 / 5) * 5);
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vkmrt/)

Comment: @Xeon06 is there some mathematical name for this logic?

Comment: Not as far as I know, but I'm no math guru. Consider asking on http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

```
function roundDownToMultiple(number, multiple) {
    return number - (number % multiple);
}   

roundDownToMultiple(86, 5); // 85

roundDownToMultiple(89, 5); // 85

roundDownToMultiple(96, 5); // 95
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [modulus operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f59bza0%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) to "round" down your number to a multiple of 5, see the example below.

```
 var x = Math.round(83.333334);

 x = x - (x % 5);
```

---

If you'd like to "*round towards zero*" (and have a correct value for negative numbers aswell) use something like this:

```
 x = Math[x < 0 ? 'ceil' : 'floor'] (x/5) * 5;
```

Comment: @bazmegakapa That's correct, and to be honest I assumed this was what OP was asking for, that's why I wrote "round". But maybe (s)he meant round to closest multiple of five.

Answer (score 2):

Using this `Math.round(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) / 5) * 5` You can get the Numbers divisible by 5.

- 100 -  is the range of the Result.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

```
Math.round(val / 5) * 5;
```

Comment: I can't find any cases where adding 2.5 will make any difference in the outcome. Examples? *Edit:* In fact, this causes incorrect results. If I enter `80`, I would be making it `82.5` which would then result in `85` ad the nearest multiple of 5, when it should still be `80`.

Comment: @animuson Apologies, in my head, I was thinking `floor`, not `round`.  Fixed!